# How to mock a class method that would be used inside an asynchronous callback?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am new to Jest and trying to wrap my head around this testing framework. My problem is understanding about the behaviour of es6 class mocking inside an asynchronous code. Example i have an exported class like this:

```js
//util_tests.ts
export default class Utils{
  getMemberAccounts = (): Promise<Number> => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(5));
}
```

and then the file i wanted to test (the function i want to mock is getMemberAccounts):

```js
//test.ts
import Util from './util_test'
import logger from '../common/logger';
import _ from 'lodash';

const util = new Util();
util.getMemberAccounts().then(test =>{
  logger.info(test); // this would have been populated with mocked data
});

setTimeout(async ()=> {
  let test = await util.getMemberAccounts();
  logger.info(test); // this wouldnt have mocked data, why? and how to solve this ?
}, 0);

export default class Test{
  
}
```

My test file is like this:

```js
import Util from '../src/test/util_test'
import Test from '../src/test/test'
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils'

jest.mock('../src/test/util_test', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getMemberAccounts: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        accounts: [
          {
            id: '0zh8ap6luxoijne8qlfu1sg',
            name: 'test',
            officeNumber: '23',
            emailAddress: 'string@gmail'
          }
        ]
      }
      )
    };
  });
});

describe('Test', () => {
  let testCase: Test;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mocked(Util).mockClear();
    testCase = new Test();
  })

  test('test-case', async () => {
    
    
  })
});
```

Why does my mocking doesnt work in setTimeout function? is it because it's related to the nature of setTimeout and callbacks ? How do i mock the function of the class in this case?

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Does `logger.info(test)` use original implementation, or else? What you describe isn't a widely known problem, so please elaborate.

Comment: @EstusFlask it does not work means that my mocking method return undefined. It SHOULD return the data that i populated in the test file. and logger info is a original implementation but it isnt important. the important part is that the value test is undefined in the setTimeout callback.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. What you said sounds like you have mock reset somewhere - in jest config or else. And mock reset shouldn't be ever used widely because it results in such problems. Use mock clear and mock restore only. Btw, what you did in test.ts will make it difficult to test and maintain. Asynchronous side effects on import shouldn't be done, `async` and setTimeout shouldn't be mixed, the latter is unaware of a promise that `async` returns.

Comment: @EstusFlask the crazy part is that inside setTimeout it's still a mock function. Just the mocking function getMemberAccount is returning undefined. And if i remove jest.mock then getMemberAccount return 5 like normal.

Comment: @EstusFlask my example is just a demonstration of a bigger problem in my production system. And i cant change how things get implemented. My task is unit testing the problem above and i cant get the mocking right. That setTimeout is actually an asynchronous transaction in typeorm typescript. But i guess u dont want to read all that

Comment: *the crazy part is that inside setTimeout it's still a mock function. Just the mocking function getMemberAccount is returning undefined.* - this is how mock reset works, double check that you have no `resetMocks` in configuration and no `*reset*` in tests because this is the first suspect here. There's nothing in Jest that would make a mock behave like that in general in asynchronous calls.

Comment: @EstusFlask i am pretty sure that there is no resetMock at anywhere. 

Comment: Then please provide a minimal way to reproduce the problem because this isn't something that is natural for Jest. There's no way how mocked function can lose the implementation without this explicitly being made somewhere. The problem with your code is that you don't have control over execution of `logger.info(test)` and cannot chain a promise, it could happen in another test where you mocked it differently.

Comment: @EstusFlask actually you can use console.log just fine. It would return undefined. I repoduced it using a new project. The problem's still persists. You can test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it here if anyone needed help. So the problem is that setTimeout invoke a function to be called back later and there is no way jest knew about it and the test is finished. therefore jest cant mock the value into the function anymore. So we need to mock the setTimeout timer to resolve the value inside the callback function.